# Mailer - link to specific object id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When a new article is created I want to send an email to the users with a notification about it and a link to read the article.

So I have this in my controller#create: (I pass the user and the article's object)

```
UserMailer.artcile_notification(user, articleobj).deliver
```

Then in user_mailer.rb I have this method:

```
  def artcile_notification(user, artobj)
    @articlenotif = artobj
   mail(to: user.email, subject: "New Article posted!")
  end
```

Then on the email I want to point to the article. Like /articles/[:id]. I tried with several ways and my best tryouts were these:

```
<p>
  <%= link_to "Read Article1", :controller => "articles", :only_path => false, :id => @articlenotif.id %>
  <%= link_to "Read Article2", articles_path(@articlenotif.id) %>
</p>
```

The Read Article1 link returns this url: `http://localhost:3000/articles?id=29`

and the Rad Article2 link returns this url `http://articles.29/`

I surely need the only_path option but also the link I need is something like `http://localhost:3000/articles/29`

I understand that I can take "Read Article1"'s link and make it redirect to the correct article but is it really necessary? I think Rails handles that somehow, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, use `article_path` instead of `articles_path`

```
<%= link_to "Read Article1", article_path(@articlenotif.id) %>
```

Comment: oh my...missed that :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: `<%= link_to "Read Article1", @articlenotif %>` should be enough.